# Using divergence theorem on sphere

Tags: integration

I have a Vector $F = \frac {\bf r}{\|{\bf r}\|}$ where $r = xi+yj+zk$
I want to find

$$\iint F \cdot n  dS$$

using the divergence theorem, where S is a sphere of radius 2 centered at the origin.

Now, I know that $F = n$ (both are unit normal vectors), and when I take that I get

$$\iint 1 dS $$, which should be the surface area of the sphere.

But how do I do this problem using divergence theorem? I tried finding the divergence, and using spherical coordinates, but I get a $ln(0)$ term. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not sure what you mean by $r=x^2 i+y^2 j+z^2 k$. Assumedly you mean ${\bf r}=x{\bf i}+y{\bf j}+z{\bf k}$.

The divergence is best taken in spherical coordinates where ${\bf F}=1{\bf e}_r$ and the [divergence is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Spherical_coordinates)

$$\nabla\cdot{\bf F}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^21)=\frac{2}{r}.$$
Then the divergence theorem says that your surface integral should be equal to
$$\int \nabla\cdot{\bf F}\,dV=\int dr\,d\theta\,d\varphi\,\,r^2\sin\theta\,\frac{2}{r}=8\pi\int_0^2 dr\,r=4\pi\cdot 2^2,$$
which is indeed the surface area of the sphere.

Comment: doesn't the divergence theorem have to have a triple integral?